# Is it possible to "join" documents in MongoDB and delete the "parent" document but still keep the "child" document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building up a CRUD app with the MEAN stack.
I have an `patients` schema and I need to add a `medical history` to those patients, I was wondering if I could use like a "join" like in mysql to relate those documents. And if yes how could I keep the the `medical history` even after the patient is deleted.

Here's my `patient` schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var paciente_schema = new Schema({

nombre: {type: String, required: true},
estado: {type: String, required: true, default: "En espera"},
fecha: {type: String, required: true},
edad: {type: String, required: true},
sexo: {type: String, required: true},
direccion: {type: String, required: true},
contacto: {type: String, required: true}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Paciente", paciente_schema);
```

App.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Paciente = require("./models/pacientes");
var dateTime = require("node-datetime");

var app = express();


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var mongoDB = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pacientes', {
    useMongoClient: true
});


app.use(bodyParser.json()); //leyendo parámetros de una petición JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //facilita la lectura de los parámetros de una petición
app.use(express.static("client")); //servido de archivos estáticos


//obteniendo los pacientes
app.get("/app/pacientes", function(req, res){
//find busca todos los datos de la DB
    Paciente.find(function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error obteniendo los pacientes");
        }else{
            res.send(pacientes);
        }
//Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}});
    });

});


//obteniendo UN paciente
app.get("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//método findOne el cual recibe el id del paciente a buscar en la DB
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}}, function(err, paciente){
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error obteniendo el paciente deseado");
        }else{
            res.json(paciente);
        }

    });
});


//agregando pacientes
app.post("/app/pacientes", function(req, res){
//creando paciente con los datos enviados por el user en el cuerpo de la petición
    Paciente.create(req.body, function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error al agregar paciente");
        }else{
            res.json(pacientes)
        }

    });
});


//actualizando paciente
app.put("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//creamos una variable(actualiza) la cual tomará los atributos a actualizar y se enviará como un query en el método update
    var actualiza = {

        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        estado: req.body.estado,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        edad: req.body.edad,
        sexo: req.body.sexo,
        contacto: req.body.contacto

    };
//encontramos un paciente y lo actualizamos, pasamos el query con los atributos actualizados
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, actualiza, function(err, paciente){     
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error actualizando" + err);
        }else{
            res.json(paciente);
        }

    });

/* === SOL === */
//  req.body.fecha = new Date(req.body.fecha);
//  console.log("=== "+req.body.fecha);
//  Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}});

});


//borrar paciente
app.delete("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//método para encontrar y eliminar un dato en la DB, el _id es el identificador en la DB
    Paciente.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error al eliminar el paciente");
        }else{
            res.json(pacientes)
        }

    });
});



//app corriendo en puerto 8888
app.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log("App corriendo en 8888");
});
```

I thought about creating a new Schema for the medical history and then make a ref to the "parent" schema which is Paciente. I hope I made myself clear.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var historia_schema = new Schema({

    historia: {type: String, required: true},
    paciente: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Paciente", required: true}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Historia", historia_schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), particularly [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to do a left-outer join.

```
Paciente.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: 'historias',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'paciente',
            as: 'historia'
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, pacientes) {
    // each document will have an "historia" array of their medical records
});
```

You might find it also useful to set up a [virtual population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)

```
paciente_schema.virtual('historia', {
    ref: 'Historia',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'paciente'
});
```

That way you can do somewhere

```
Paciente.find({}).populate('historia').exec(function (err, pacientes) {
    // each "paciente" will have an "historia" array of their medical records
});
```